# Meaning of status constants of psutil Process class

Tags: python-3.x, process, psutil

I need detail description of status constants of psutil Process class. I need to define whether process is up or down based on the status returned by psutil Process. Any link describing these status clearly will be helpful. I am able to get information for some of normal states in process lifecycle such as running or defunct or stopped.

No proper documentation provided for the status constants (in psutil documentation). There is only two word explaination, such as for STATUS_WAKEKILL, information given is "wake kill".